# Thread blocks my Android UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, class, nested

I have a problem with java Threads in my Android app. My nested thread blocks my UI, how can i resolve this?

MyClass.java

```
package com.knobik.gadu;

import android.util.Log;

public class MyClass {

    public void StartTheThread() {

        Thread Nested = new Thread( new NestedThread() );
        Nested.run();
    }

    private class NestedThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                Log.d( "DUPA!", "debug log SPAM!!" );
            }

        }

    }

}
```

and this is how i run it:

```
package com.knobik.gadu;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class AndroidGadu extends Activity {
    public static final String LogAct = "AndroidGadu";

    public void OnClickTest(View v) {

        MyClass test = new MyClass();
        test.StartTheThread();

    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



    }
}
```

Could you help me? I'm literaly stuck ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***My nested thread blocks my UI***

You need to use `.start()` instead of `.run()`. That is, replace

```
Nested.run();
```

with

```
Nested.start();
```

(`run` is just an ordinary method. `start()` is the method that actually spawns a new thread, which in turn runs `run`)

Comment: +1, I see so many people invoking `run()` instead of `start()` on their `Thread` objects. :(

Comment: well, my java expiriance is 2 days long. Thank you for your answer. Ill post if this helps :)

Comment: Ah, I can just say that people with 2 years of experience does this too ;-)  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

This code is a problem:

```
while (true) {
    Log.d( "DUPA!", "debug log SPAM!!" );
}
```

A busy wait hogs the CPU.

Comment: not really a decent OS will spread the load around and the real cause is not starting the thread

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.knobik.gadu;

import android.util.Log;

public class MyClass {

    public void StartTheThread() {
        Thread Nested = new Thread( new NestedThread() );
        Nested.run(); // Change this to Nested.start();
    }

    private class NestedThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {

            while (true) { // infinite loop logical error
                Log.d( "DUPA!", "debug log SPAM!!" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```