# Android Thread Blocking UI Unless Using Synchronized

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I was trying to figure out the fastest rate at which my phone's camera could take pictures. The object I use to manage the camera (without the camera logic) looks like this:

```
public class PictureTaker {
    private boolean mIsTakingPicture;

    public void takePicture() {
        mIsTakingPicture = true;
    }

    public boolean isTakingPicture() {
        return mIsTakingPicture;
    }
}
```

In my activity, I create a new thread and post a runnable to it to start looping and taking pictures when the user taps a button. I stop the thread by tapping the button again.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CameraTestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private HandlerThread mThread;
    private Handler mThreadHandler;
    private volatile boolean mTestingCameraSpeed;
    private PictureTaker mPictureTaker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_test);

        mThread = new HandlerThread("testThread");
        mThread.start();
        mThreadHandler = new Handler(mThread.getLooper());
        mPictureTaker = new PictureTaker();
    }

    public void toggleDoingStuff(final View view) {
        Button b = (Button)view;
        if(mTestingCameraSpeed) {
            mTestingCameraSpeed = false;
            b.setText("Start camera");
        } else {
            mTestingCameraSpeed = true;

            mThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    loopUntilStop();
                }
            });
            b.setText("Stop camera");
        }
    }

    private void loopUntilStop() {
        for(;;) {
            if(!mTestingCameraSpeed) break;

            if(!mPictureTaker.isTakingPicture()) {
                Log.d("CameraTestActivity", "Taking picture at time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                mPictureTaker.takePicture();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since booleans are atomic and I don't mind missing an update, I didn't wrap the check for `mIsTestingCameraSpeed` in `loopUntilStop()` in a `synchronized` block. (**EDIT:** as mttdbrd and Kevin Krumwiede pointed out, without synchronization or making the variable volatile, the thread might not see the changes).

Anyway, the above code blocks the UI thread. However, changing `takePicture()` to

```
public void takePicture() {
    mIsTakingPicture = false;
}
```

doesn't block the UI, but then `mIsTakingPicture` isn't set correctly. To prevent blocking and use the first version of `takePicture()`, I had to change `isTakingPicture()` to use a lock:

```
public boolean isTakingPicture() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return mIsTakingPicture;
    }
}
```

Why would not using a lock block the UI when `mIsTakingPicture` is set to `true` but not `false`? I checked the [Java documentation on intrinsic locks and synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and didn't find anything that would explain it. I've also had a look at these SO questions and none of them answered my question:

- [Android :UI Thread Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247915/android-ui-thread-blocked)
- [Thread blocks my Android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219597/thread-blocks-my-android-ui)
- [Thread blocking UI in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845388/thread-blocking-ui-in-android)
- [Android asynchronous post blocks UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497560/android-asynchronous-post-blocking-ui-thread-still)
- [Android UI Thread Block when calling AsynchTask.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001726/android-ui-thread-block-when-calling-asynchtask-get)
- [load textures into a thread blocks the mainUI in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625632/load-textures-into-a-thread-blocks-the-mainui-in-android)

**EDIT:** [Here](http://pastebin.com/kZ5K8SWq) are the logs for the ANR. The first two lines indicate that the thread is suspended waiting for a lock, and looking at line 216, it seems that the test thread does acquire a lock at some point. Starting at line 161 of thread_list.cc, the OS tries to acquire two different mutexes, but I'm not sure if those are related to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you're even allowed to use the camera API outside the UI thread.  Unless it's explicitly documented that you can, you should assume you can't.  Android's APIs are mostly designed to be called in the UI thread.

Second, there's more to thread safety in Java than atomicity; you also have to worry about visibility.  The worker thread may not see writes to `mTestingCameraSpeed` unless you make it `volatile` or synchronize the reads *and* the writes.  Likewise, synchronizing the read of `mIsTakingPicture` is pointless unless you also synchronize the write.  (Or again, make it `volatile`.)

Third, your problem doesn't make any sense as you describe it, so it's probably actually caused by one of the aforementioned issues.

Assuming you're using [`Camera#takePicture(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29), I'd suggest using one of the callbacks to start taking the next picture.  That should give you the maximum practical rate.

Edit: It *should* be impossible for `mThread.getLooper()` to return `null` after calling `mThread.start()`, and I'm not exactly sure what would happen if it did.  So this is just a shot in the dark.  But try changing this:

```
    mThread.start();
    mThreadHandler = new Handler(mThread.getLooper());
```

...to this:

```
    mThread.start();
    Looper looper = mThread.getLooper();
    Log.d("DERP", "looper is " + looper);
    mThreadHandler = new Handler(looper);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about most APIs being designed for the UI thread; I did take pictures outside of the main thread, but I guess I shouldn't rely on that. Those are all valid points about concurrency as well, but what I don't understand is why the UI thread could block or deadlock in the above scenario; where is it waiting?

Comment: @Shane_S You mentioned that you've simplified your code for this post.  Could it be that the worker thread is looping inside a synchronized block, and therefore holding onto the lock?

Comment: The code as it is written above still blocks (without `synchronized` in `isTakingPicture()`, that is).

Comment: @Shane_S I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I've added a link to the ANR log, if that helps at all. Thanks for the suggestion to use the callback to initiate the pictures as well; I ended up using that to get the average speed. I'd vote your answer up, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: No dice, unfortunately. And it looks like [Handler throws an exception when passed a null Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

All reads and writes of variables must be synchronized. A read is not guaranteed to reflect the current value of a variable unless that read is synchronized, even if the variable is marked volatile.

The Goetz book on concurrency is very clear on synchronized: if in doubt, synchronize. If you don't have the book, this article will help: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075692/java-concurrency/avoid-synchronization-deadlocks.html

To wit:

> In general, you should synchronize whenever you are reading any
>   variable that might have been previously written by a different
>   thread, or whenever you are writing any variable that might be
>   subsequently read by another thread.

Comment: You're right that I should synchronize the reads and writes, and thanks for the article. But the code that blocks doesn't contain `synchronized`, so where could it be blocking?

Comment: @Shane_S Maybe I misunderstood the question but I think you're trying to read a variable on one thread that is being written on another thread. The variable value on the reading thread is cached, so you're reading stale data. You need to synchronize to make sure that your read on one thread is _synchronized with_ a write on another thread. It's not really blocking so much as stuck in a tight loop always reading a stale "true" that keeps it in the loop.

Comment: That makes sense, but somehow the UI thread hangs as well. Even if the worker thread were stuck in an infinite loop, I don't understand how that would block the UI.

Comment: @Shane_S Actually, looking more closely at your code, you've got the thread calling a method on the main UI thread. That's not how Handlers work. This is all kind of backwards. You need to put the loop until stop in the thread and then post back to the main ui thread when finished. The docs are very clear that the Runnable posted to the Handler will be run on the thread from which the Runnable is posted. That is, on the main UI thread. There doesn't appear to be any actual work in another thread.

Comment: well, you do have another thread, but all it does is all a method on the main thread in a tight loop. this won't work.

Comment: Where do the docs say that? [The documentation for Handler#post(Runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) says that it runs "on the thread to which this handler is attached", and using [the constructor taking a Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28android.os.Looper%29) says that the Handler will "[u]se the provided Looper instead of the default one".